# window.onmesage vs window.addEventListener("message", onMessage);

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, event-listener

I was wondering what is the difference between those two ways of listening a message.

Here is my assumptions:

#### `window.onmesage = onMessage`

This assign a function to the `onmessage` attribute of the `window` object. It will be executed every time I receive a message on my page. It allows to have only 1 listener for messages.

vs.

#### `window.addEventListener("message", onMessage);`

This adds an event listener to the `message` event. It will be executed every time I receive a message on my page. It allows to have multiple listener for messages.

#### Differences

If I call many times the first one, I will always have 1 function that is executed when receiving a message.

If I call X times the second one, I will have many listeners and when receiving a message, my `onMessage` function will be executed X times

### Question

Are my assumptions correct?

Comment: if `onMessage` is always referring to the same function, then no, you'll have only one handler call per event. The difference is that if another script does `onmessage = myHandler` yours will be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your assumption is correct. Based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6348533/12715723) of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6348494/12715723):

> ... *addEventListener does not overwrite existing event handlers, whereas `onmessage` overrides any existing `onmessage = fn` event handlers ...*

So only one function is executed if it includes as callback in `window.onmessage` while many functions can be executed using `window.addEventListener`